# systemd stuck on mounting an encrypted volume

Tags: arch-linux, systemd

systemd seems to stuck on mounting an encrypted volume, when I set the `init` to  `/usr/sbin/systemd` in grub.cfg,

I have one line in `/etc/crypttab`

`secure /dev/sda8 /etc/cb.key`

That works with original init program, but when I switched to systemd, it stuck at

[ OK ] Reached target Encrypted Volume

And it got the right device name, right mapper name, but just won't go on. Wait for like 60s, I got a timeout message.

How should I debug it?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but you could try submitting a "support request" for the systemd package on http://bugs.archlinux.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bug on systemd & LVM,

I run LVM on a crypted device, which systemd failed to detect. When I finally entered the sulogin interface, I found that `vgchange -ay` has no effects (It failed to detect the volume group), no idea why. But with legacy init scripts, that works.

Now I re-formatted the disk, and uses that partition directly, and the boot continues without problem.